# Setting up an SVN Server using SVNServe in Amazon ec2 Ubuntu Linux

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, ssh-tunnel, svn

This has been a headache. Where to begin? So far, I've followed [this](http://articles.slicehost.com/2007/9/5/introduction-to-svnserve) article, along with its [follow-up](http://articles.slicehost.com/2007/9/5/using-ssh-with-svnserve) tutorial and my output when I try to do

```
svn+engine_ssh://[insert-elastic-ip-here]/var/svn/test
```

I get the following output:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
svn: To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from 'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file.
svn: Network connection closed unexpectedly
```

My config file looks like the following in the tunnels section (on ec2 server):

[tunnels]

```
engine_ssh = /usr/bin/ssh -l username
```

I have the same listing in tunnels on my local machine, only using my local username as opposed to my remote username.

I'm guessing the issue is that I need to generate an ssh key and somehow set it up on my server? The issue is that ec2 the file used is called `hosts.pem` as the `IdentityFile` for my ssh config file.

Thus, what am I doing wrong here? What can I do? Are there alternatives to using SSH + svn for my server?

If anyone needs more info I'd be glad to post it.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you'll need for your server to allow login over SSH in one way or another - be it via allowing password login in your sshd_config or using key logins - see [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/280489/72586) for some details on getting key login working.

You're overcomplicating the checkout process a bit; your username spec can be included in the checkout URL, no tunnel config needed.  This'll work just fine:

```
svn+ssh://remoteusername@[insert-elastic-ip-here]/var/svn/test
```

---

> Are there alternatives to using SSH + svn for my server?

Yes, absolutely.  Your question's title references `svnserve`, but that's not accurate, since you aren't using it - that's method 1, and is pretty basic.  You don't want to use it over the internet, as there's no encryption - of data or credentials.

Method 2 is the SSH method that you're presently working with.

Method 3 is a web server using WebDAV to serve the repository; the typical go-to option is Apache and the `mod_dav_svn` module.  You can definitely take a look at it if you don't like the SSH option; it's a little more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing from the error you're seeing that you haven't put your personal ssh key onto the remote machine.

A quick solution to your problem would probably be to just add your local id_rsa.pub to the server's authorized keys file.

First: `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Second: copy that full string and then edit `/home/USERNAME/.ssh/authorized_keys` pasting the id_rsa.pub string there.

If you don't have a personal ssh key yet, just run `ssh-keygen`.

Optionally if you don't want to do that, you can just use the ssh key for the EC2 machine by specifying the SVN_SSH environment variable.

`export SVN_SSH="ssh -i path_to_your/key/goes/here"`